# Is there a synthetic definition of the $0$-Hecke monoid of $S_n$?

Tags: symmetric-groups, monoid, algebraic-combinatorics, hecke-algebras

**Background.** Let $n$ be a nonnegative integer, and let $S_n$ denote the $n$-th symmetric group. The *$0$-Hecke monoid* $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ is defined to be the monoid given by generators $t_1, t_2, \ldots, t_{n-1}$ and relations

- $t_i^2 = t_i$ for every $i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$;
- $t_i t_{i+1} t_i = t_{i+1} t_i t_{i+1}$ for every $i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-2\right\}$;
- $t_i t_j = t_j t_i$ for every $i$ and $j$ in $\left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$ satisfying $\left|i-j\right| > 1$.

(This is a particular case of a more general construction -- that of the $0$-Hecke monoid of a Coxeter group --; but I want to focus on the symmetric group.)

The monoid $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ has cardinality $n!$. More precisely, for every permutation $w \in S_n$, we can define an element $t_w$ of $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ by setting

$t_w = t_{i_1} t_{i_2} \cdots t_{i_k}$, where $\left(i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k\right)$ is a [reduced word](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/combinat/sage/combinat/permutation.html#sage.combinat.permutation.Permutation.reduced_words) for $w$ in $S_n$.

This element $t_w$ does not depend on the choice of the reduced word. The family $\left(t_w\right)_{w \in S_n}$ contains each element of $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ exactly once. Thus, we can define a monoid structure $\left(S_n, *\right)$ on the set $S_n$ as follows: For any $a \in S_n$ and $b \in S_n$, define $a * b$ to be the unique element of $S_n$ satisfying $t_{a * b} = t_a t_b$. Then, $\left(S_n, *\right)$ is an isomorphic copy of the $0$-Hecke monoid $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ whose elements are those of $S_n$. It has various interesting properties, which are spread across the literature (apparently very popular as exercises).

**Question.** Is there an equivalent definition of $*$ that is "synthetic", i.e., does not use the decomposition of a permutation into adjacent transpositions? (My intuition for $a * b$ is something along the lines of "the join of $a$ and $b$ on the Bruhat order lattice, if one squints hard enough to forget that the Bruhat order is not a lattice and that $*$ is not commutative".)

**Motivation.** For comparison, here is a similar object where the answer is "Yes". We define a *zeroed monoid* to be a monoid $M$ with a specified element $0$ which satisfies $0m = m0 = 0$ for every $m \in M$. We can define the *nilCoxeter monoid* $C_0\left(S_n\right)$ to be the monoid given by generators $u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_{n-1}, 0$ and relations

- $0 u_i = u_i 0 = 0$ for every $i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$;
- $u_i^2 = 0$ for every $i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$;
- $u_i u_{i+1} u_i = u_{i+1} u_i u_{i+1}$ for every $i \in \left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-2\right\}$;
- $u_i u_j = u_j u_i$ for every $i$ and $j$ in $\left\{1, 2, \ldots, n-1\right\}$ satisfying $\left|i-j\right| > 1$.

Similar results as for $H_0\left(S_n\right)$ hold; in particular, we can define a $u_w \in C_0\left(S_n\right)$ for every $w \in S_n$, and the family $\left(u_w\right)_{w \in S_n}$ contains each element of $C_0\left(S_n\right) \setminus \left\{0\right\}$ exactly once. We can again transfer this zeroed monoid structure onto the set $S_n \cup \left\{0\right\}$; in other words, we can define a binary operation $\sharp$ on $S_n \cup \left\{0\right\}$ by $u_{a \sharp b} = u_a u_b$ for all $a, b \in S_n \cup \left\{0\right\}$ (where I set $u_0 = 0$). But this multiplication $\sharp$ can be described without using reduced words: Namely, for any $a \in S_n$ and $b \in S_n$, we have

$a \sharp b = \begin{cases} ab, & \text{ if } \ell\left(ab\right) = \ell\left(a\right) + \ell\left(b\right); \\ 0, & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$,

where $\ell\left(w\right)$ means the Coxeter length of a permutation of $w$ (that is, the number of inversions of $w$). Of course, the Coxeter length of a permutation $w$ is the length of any reduced expression of $w$, but it can also be defined as the number of inversions of $w$, which does not rely on the representation of a permutation as composition of adjacent transpositions. I am looking for a similar description for the $0$-Hecke monoid.

(Note: None of the results above is mine, but it is hard to find proofs for them in the literature, so I don't even know whom to cite.)

Comment: Would this mathoverflow question: [Is the following construction of the 0-Hecke monoid (well) known?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/81539/is-the-following-construction-of-the-0-hecke-monoid-well-known) be relevant?

Comment: @JEPin: Thank you! This is what I was looking for (although a proof would be much preferred). Care to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment converted to an answer on OP's suggestion.

This mathoverflow question: [Is the following construction of the 0-Hecke monoid (well) known?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81539/is-the-following-construction-of-the-0-hecke-monoid-well-known) might be relevant to your question.

Let me also mention two possibly relevant references
[On the representation theory of finite J-trivial monoids](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.3455.pdf) by
Tom Denton, Florent Hivert, Anne Schilling, Nicolas M. Thiéry

[A Combinatorial Formula for Orthogonal Idempotents in the $0$-Hecke Algebra of the Symmetric Group](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.2401.pdf) by
Tom Denton

Answer (score 3):

Monoid H_0(S_n) can be defined as a monoid of permutation matrices under a special kind of multiplication, or equivalently of special integer matrices (unit-Monge matrices) under standard tropical multiplication. See my paper for details: https://doi.org/10.1007/s00453-013-9830-z

I am curious about your remark that the monoid's properties are popular as exercises: do you have any examples of those?

Comment: Wow, this is a nice and completely unexpected interpretation! Am I reading you right (reading between the lines, as I think you only say explicitly where the generators are mapped to) that if $a$ and $b$ are two permutations in $S_n$, and if $i, j \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}$, then $\ell_{i,j}\left(a*b\right) = \min\limits_{k \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,n\right\}}\left(\ell_{i,k}\left(a\right) + \ell_{k,j}\left(b\right)\right)$, where $\ell_{i,j}\left(w\right)$ denotes the number of all $p \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,j\right\}$ satisfying $w\left(p\right) \geq i$ ?

Comment: As to the exercises, I believe I meant that everyone who uses the properties tend to leave them as exercises. I don't remember the details any more (I think I was reading [Hivert/Schilling/Thiéry](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1513729967) in particular).

Comment: (Correction: Read "$w\left(p\right) > i$" for "$w\left(p\right) \geq i$" in my first comment.)

Comment: Okay, whether or not I was reading you right, my claim is true (I've just proved it by checking that it holds whenever $b = s_u$ for some $u \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,u-1\right\}$, and then leveraging associativity of the tropical matrix product and of the $0$-Hecke $*$ product to conclude that it holds for all $a$ and $b$). What a nice result!

Comment: This seems related to Proposition 3.2 in [Z. Hamaker and V. Reiner, *Weak order and descents for monotone triangles*, European Journal of Combinatorics (2020) 103083](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ejc.2020.103083) ([arXiv:1809.10571v2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1809.10571v2)). Could the standard embedding of the symmetric group $S_n$ into $\operatorname{MT}_n$ (by treating each permutation matrix as an ASM, and sending it to the corresponding monotone triangle) be $H_n\left(0\right)$-equivariant, where the action of $H_n\left(0\right)$ on $S_n$ is via the $0$-Hecke product?